# why is the screenshot taken in objective c blank white image?

Tags: objective-c, screenshot

I want to take screenshot of the actual screen as viewed by the user on the iphone/ipad then present option for the user to share/save it

I have code and tried several but each time all i get is either a blank white or black image.  The image is the same size of the screen.

The screen actual background is plain white and has white buttons on it, i can never capture the buttons.

```
  NSLog(@"Taking The Screenshot");
  

 CALayer *layer =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController.layer;
 CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, NO, scale);
 [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
 screengrab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 
 //new code for sharing...
 UIActivityViewController *shareVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[screengrab] applicationActivities:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you now have scenes and the app delegate window no longer works.

One way to fix this, if `self` is a VC, is to change your layer line to

```
CALayer * layer = self.view.window.rootViewController.view.layer;
```